# Invalidate caches vs rebuild project

Tags: android, android-studio

Since I already learned that Rebuild project in Android studio also does the cleaning project, now i want to know does "invalidate caches/restart" also does rebuilding project?

I use this command relatively often since android studio sometimes creates its own problem so i want to optimize using of this commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Invalidate caches**

> Android Studio makes a lot of files as caches and does not delete
>   them. This can cause trouble when there is a need to make new files,
>   so clearing caches will clear the old cache and make Android Studio
>   faster.

**Rebuild project**

> Rebuild Project. All the source files in the project are recompiled.
>   This may be necessary when the class path entries have changed, for
>   example, SDKs or libraries being used added, removed or altered.

And when we do **Invalidate caches** its first clear cache of all open projects and scanning and indexing is done then build Gradle .

> So Yes when we Invalidate cache  its build project too.

Comment: Yes i know what those commands do. My question was does command "Invalidate caches" also "rebuild project" (yes?no)

Comment: @Haris yes its true read my updates , and you can do it with your self too. both the things.

Comment: so "Invalidate cache" = invalidate caches + rebuild project?

Comment: This was top hit for: if I invalidate cache and restart my android studio project do I still need to build clean?